# No audio on Samsung Galaxy Book2 Pro 360

Tags: sound, samsung

I bought Samsung Galaxy Book2 Pro 360 and installed ubuntu 22.04 but I do not have audio. I can see that the volume bar is moving in the volume setting but no sound comes out.

Also after suspending, the screen stays blank and I need to restart the computer. This one I fixed by stopping suspend to activate.

The problem is still that I have no sound. I read that other people are having the same issues, also Samsung galaxy books have the same issue. Have anyone found any solution?

I am happy to give more information to solve this problem. I am surprised Samsung has not done anything about it. so many people, especially developers, use linux/ubuntu and there are always these kinds of problems when installing linux/ubuntu to a newer computer models. It is just annoying.

Hope you can help.

Comment: Previous generation had audio issue as well. Described here with a solution :
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2467804 You could try that.